# In pygame <alien invasion>, why my aliens appear just one row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

(instance.py)

```
    import pygame
    from settings import Settings
    from ship import Ship
    import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
    ship = Ship(ai_settings,screen)
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings,screen,ship,aliens)

    while 1:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullet(bullets)
        gf.update_alien(ai_settings,aliens)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets,aliens)

run_game()
```

(game_functions.py)

```
import pygame
import sys
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

def check_events(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets,event)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(ship,event)

def check_keydown_events(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets,event):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving['right'] = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving['left'] = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving['up'] = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving['down'] = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings,screen,ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()

def check_keyup_events(ship,event):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving['right'] = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving['left'] = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving['up'] = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving['down'] = False

def update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets,aliens):
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    aliens.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullet(bullets):
    bullets.update()
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.y < 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)

def create_fleet(ai_settings,screen,ship,aliens):
    sample_alien = Alien(ai_settings,screen)
    alien_width = sample_alien.rect.width
    alien_height = sample_alien.rect.height

    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    numbers_alien_x = int(available_space_x / ( 2 * alien_width ))
    available_space_y = ai_settings.screen_height - 3 * alien_height - ship.rect.height
    numbers_alien_y = int(available_space_y / ( 2 * alien_height ))

    for number_alien_y in range(numbers_alien_y):
        for number_alien_x in range(numbers_alien_x):
            alien = Alien(ai_settings,screen)
            alien.rect.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * number_alien_x
            alien.rect.y = alien_height + 2 * alien_height * number_alien_y
            aliens.add(alien)

def update_alien(ai_settings,aliens):
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings,aliens)
    aliens.update()

def check_fleet_edges(ai_settings,aliens):
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            change_fleet_direction(ai_settings,aliens)
            break

def change_fleet_direction(ai_settings,aliens):
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += ai_settings.fleet_drop_speed
    ai_settings.fleet_direction *= -1
```

(settings.py)

```
class Settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 700
        self.bg_color = 230,230,230

        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5

        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 15,15,15
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1

        self.alien_speed_factor = 2

        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
        self.fleet_direction = 1
```

(ship.py)

```
import pygame

class Ship(object):
    def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen):
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.screen = screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        self.moving = {'right':False,'left':False,'up':False,'down':False}
        self.centerx = float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.centery = float(self.rect.centery)
        self.speed = self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        if self.moving['right'] and self.rect.right < self.ai_settings.screen_width:
            self.centerx += self.speed
        if self.moving['left'] and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.centerx -= self.speed
        if self.moving['up'] and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.centery -= self.speed
        if self.moving['down'] and self.rect.bottom < self.ai_settings.screen_height:
            self.centery += self.speed
        self.rect.centerx = self.centerx
        self.rect.centery = self.centery

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

(bullet.py)

```
import pygame
from random import randint

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen,ship):
        super().__init__()
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.screen = screen
        self.ship = ship

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,self.ai_settings.bullet_width,self.ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.top = self.ship.rect.top
        self.rect.centerx = self.ship.rect.centerx

        self.speed = self.ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.color = randint(1,255),randint(1,255),randint(1,255)

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.speed
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,self.color,self.rect)
```

(alien.py)

```
import pygame

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen):
        super().__init__()
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.screen = screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.speed = self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
            return True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True

    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.speed * self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

My goal is create alien fleet in the whole screen.
Why is there just one row of aliens?

Comment: Hi examine, I see that you are new to stackoverflow.  Welcome!  While your question looks interesting, you'll get better responses if you can also discuss what you've tried so far, experiments run, changes made, and so on. Not many volunteers are going to wade through a program and debug it for you, so the more specific the better.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, dear my friend.

Comment: I stand corrected!  Kudos to @rbricheno.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at the [mcve page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `Alien` you `update(self)` using the value of `self.x`, but you never set this value when you run `create_fleet(...)`. So all your aliens are there already, they are just all on top of each other!

A simple solution is to set `self.x` at the same time as you set `self.rect.x` for each `Alien` when you initialize them in `create_fleet(...)`. So instead of:

```
alien.rect.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * number_alien_x
```

you would have:

```
alien.rect.x = alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * number_alien_x
```

Comment: So my error is that, all the aliens I create in `create_fleet(...)` have not define attribute `self.x` but `self.rect.x`, therefore, the `self.x` all are 0.When run `update(self)`, a line of aliens have the same attribute `self.rect.x`, so they will overlap.

Comment: Hard to believe that there is one person has patient to check this boring code.Thanks very much!

Comment: This solution is a change inside the function `create_fleet()`, which is called **outside** `while 1:` in  `run_game()`. So `create_fleet()` is updated only once (in the beginning), while the aliens are drawn consistently in `gf.update_screen()`. (`aliens.draw(screen)`).

1. Why do we need to create the fleet only once? Why isn't `create_fleet()` found inside `while 1` to create it again and again in its new position?

2. How does the location of y of the aliens can be updated continuosly if it is found inside a function that is updated only once (outside `while 1`)?

Thanks.

Comment: Same same problem came up with me. Could you explain it bit more clearly?